Why would a clean GCP instance of Ubuntu 24.04 fail to install the desktop?
I started from a pristine GCP instance of Ubuntu 24.04 LTS  I executed sudo apt update && sudo apt upgrade" followed by sudo apt install ubuntu-desktop.  Everything is new out of the box.  As the install completes, I see an error message that gdm3 failed to reload.  At this point, I captured the syslog.  As soon as I reboot (or shutdown and restart), it bricks.  From here, all I can do is delete the VM and start over.  I cannot connect even via the serial port.
My workplace has many available machines. I have tried installing the desktop there and see the same behavior. I have tried it using Ubuntu Pro Server 24.04 and the 24.10 minimal edition, all with the same result, however the desktop installs normally on Ubuntu 22.04.
Nothing I do seems to make any difference (besides retrograding the version, I mean.)  My other puzzlement is that nobody else seems to be discussing this issue; were it an endemic problem, I would expect to see it discussed in the fora.
I tried installing gdm3 manually. That eliminated the error message, but the VM still bricks on reboot. I see messages in the log file that cause me to suspect that the gdm3 is only a symptom and not the cause. I'm beginning to think that the Google Cloud Platform has a bug in the script that installs the desktop on Ubuntu 24.04. What "bugs" me is that I appear to be the only person who has reported that issue.
I'm running out of new things to try. Does anyone have any suggestions?

It was worth trying, but didn't work.  I also tried installing gdm3 manually; that eliminated the error message, but the VM still bricks on reboot.  I see messages in the log file that cause me to suspect that the gdm3 is only a symptom and not the cause.  I'm beginning to think that the Google Cloud Platform has a bug in the script that installs the desktop on Ubuntu 24.04.
What "bugs" me is that I appear to be the only person with that issue.
